# How to test if a URL is a phishing in command line using Google Safe Browsing?

Tags: safe-browsing

In Google Safe Browsing, there are two ways to test if a URL is a phishing URL:

1. lookup-based and
2. hash-based.

In this question, I focus on the hash-based solution, better for privacy, as used by browsers such as Firefox.

For this, the browser downloads a hash database `goog-phish-shavar` which is saved as  `~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/<profile_folder>/safebrowsing/goog-phish-shavar.sbstore`.

Now, I want to test a URL in command line as follows

```
test-safebrowsing-url goog-phish-shavar.sbstore http://example-phishing.com
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The files that you are looking at are Firefox-specific and so you'll need something like [sbdbdump](https://github.com/fmarier/sbdbdump) to extract the hash prefixes from it:

```
cd ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/<profile_folder>/safebrowsing/   
~/sbdbdump/dump.py -v --name goog-phish-shavar . > ~/goog-phish-shavar.hashes
```

and then you'll have to convert a URL to its possible hashes following the [hashing rules](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/urls-hashing). [regexp-lookup.py](https://github.com/fmarier/safebrowsing-tools/blob/master/regex-lookup.py) can help with that.

Finally, you'll have to check all of the URL hashes against the list of prefixes. If you find any matches, you need to make a [request for the full hashes](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/update-api#checking-urls) that start with that prefix.

Comment: super interesting, thanks. In Python, that's perfect. Do you also have a snippet about the completion part?

Comment: No, I haven't done that part. Also, you'll need an API key for that.

Answer (score 0):

For [Google Safe Browsing v3](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v3/index), there is https://github.com/Stefan-Code/gglsbl3.

For [Google Safe Browsing v4](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/index), there is https://github.com/afilipovich/gglsbl

They both support command line usage of hash-based analysis.